# How to fix Apache 2.4 Require not allow here when starting

Tags: apache, apache2, httpd.conf, apache2.4

Getting the below error  when starting apache 2.4.

```
httpd[11435]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 22 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost1.conf:
httpd[11435]: Require not allowed here
```

The following line causes this error in vhost1.conf

```
<VirtualHost myserver:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    Require all granted
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost myserver:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    Require all granted
</VirtualHost>
```

What is wrong with this? How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Require inside Directory. i.e

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Require all granted
<Directory>
```